# Datepicker and tabs

Tags: jquery, tabs, datepicker

I am using some tabs in a web app I am developing, inside one of the tabs, I am using a Jquery datepicker object, initialied like so.

```
<!-- in the html tab code -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href=
    "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datetime1" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>


<p> Date: <input type= "text" id="datetime1"/></input></p>
```

This works ok, but then when I switch to one of the other tabs, and then switch back, the Jquery datepicker no longer works, it is just dead upon clicking. Anyone have problems with Jquery stuff and tabs, or will I need to post some of my tab code as well?

Comment: are you loading contents of tabs with ajax dynamically??

Comment: I am using angular JS/angular strap

Comment: Get used to add a `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });` at the beggining of your JQuery code. It will avoid you a lot of problems in the future. Also, where are declared your tabs ? You don't use JQueryUI tabs ?!

Comment: I will look into Jquery tabs

Comment: @TCHdvlp, this led to the same behavior. I tried to initialize the datepicker inside the tabs, from within a $(document).ready block, and I got the same effect.

Comment: What the console tells you ? Any error message when clicking ?

Comment: It is saying datepicker is not a function. Would the problem be that I have included JQuery inside the index.html, as well as this particular tab?